# Residential Post Tension Slab Setup

Tags: concrete

**Background:**  Residential single story post-tension slab approximately 2300 sq. ft. new construction.  Contractor has installed formwork and laid out post tension cables.

Contractor has "overstripped" the sheathing from the post tension cables approximately 3" on both ends.  In other words there is 3" of exposed cable between the sheathing and the anchorage points on both ends of the cable. This is the part inside of the formwork.

**Question:** Is it acceptable practice for the steel tension cables to be left exposed to the concrete in this manner when it is poured?

I've spent hours trying to find an answer but can't.  Unfortunately it is 2 days before pour is scheduled and the job site isn't close and I don't have a good picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: anchor live end]

Yes, it's okay. The cable is covered with grease for protection against corrosion. That over-stripping is to make sure the anchorage engages the steel, not the plastic sleeve!

And the grease allows for the cable to be pulled by the hydraulic jack.
There are a variety of alternative anchors and details, grouted sleeves or greased sleeves, etc. But this is common for one or two-story light construction slabs on grade.

Of course, one should follow the approved plans and shop drawings.